# Replace user folder with ~ and // with /

Tags: regex, terminal

I'm working on an extension for [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) that uses `touch` to create a new file in the currently selected folder in Finder and then copies the path to the new file. As I wasn't sure if there was a command that could copy the path to this newly created file, I use `find` to locate the file which works great. I then use `pbcopy` to copy the path to my clipboard. The format of the path that gets copied is `/Users/doug/Desktop//me.md`.

I would like to replace `/Users/doug` with `~` and replace the `//` between **Desktop** & **me.md** with `/` so the final path is `~/Desktop/me.md`.

If it helps, here is my entire script I'm using in Alfred:

```
folder=`osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set theFolder to POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias)'`
cd "$folder"
touch {query}
find "$folder" -maxdepth 1 -mmin -1 -name "*.md" | pbcopy
```

The `{query}` field is replaced with what is typed in Alfred which, in this case, will be the file name of the newly created file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using sed:

```
find "$folder" -maxdepth 1 -mmin -1 -name "*.md" | sed -e 's#/Users/doug#~#;s#//#/#' | pbcopy
```

Comment: Wow. Easy indeed. Thanks. I had never heard of `sed` before.